# How to properly test a functional interface?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test this source with Junit and Mockito but with no sucess.
This source try to avoid a if structure on multiple payment options, using a Java 8 functional interface.

```
public String method(){
    EnumMap<PaymentType, Function<String, String>> paymentTypeConsumerEnumMap = new EnumMap<>(PaymentType.class);
    paymentTypeConsumerEnumMap.put(PaymentType.PAYTM, this::handlePayTmPaymentType);
    return paymentTypeConsumerEnumMap.get(PaymentType.PAYTM).apply(PaymentType.CREDIT_CARD.name());
}

private String handlePayTmPaymentType(String s) {
    return "paytm payment selected";
}
```

I'm not being able to mock and test the .apply sctructure. The private method is not a problem.

Comment: Please show your attempted test.

Comment: What aspect of this are you trying to test? `method` always returns "paytm payment selected".